# How to convert a column of arrays into a column with the sum of each array in Spark?

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Every approach I have tried leaves me with a sum of the entire column. Each row has an array filled with doubles. What I need is a column of sums for each row.

So you start with a dataframe that looks like this:

```
id   c2   c3
-------------------------
1     1   [2.0, 1.0, 0.0]
2     2   [0.0, 0,0, 0.0]
```

And as a result I want this:

```
id   c2   c3sum
-------------------------
1     1   3.0
2     2   0.0
```

I tried using the sum method after doing a `groupBy` on "id". I also tried using a `udf`:

```
def mySum(arr:Seq[Double]):Double=arr.reduceLeft(_+_)
val dfsum = df.withColumn("c3sum", mySum($"c3"))
```

These and other variants of the `udf` have always returned the sum of everything in the column. As a test I also tried using `array.max` to just get the maximum number for each array instead of summing them, and it returned the max for the entire column. Therefore it is likely some basic syntax issue I am not understanding.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider leveraging `Dataset`'s `map` with `sum` instead of relying on UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  (1, 1, Array(2.0, 1.0, 0.0)),
  (2, 2, Array(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
).toDF("id", "c2", "c3")

df.
  withColumn("c3", coalesce($"c3", lit(Array[Double]()))).
  as[(Int, Int, Array[Double])].
  map{ case (id, c2, c3) => (id, c2, c3.sum) }.
  toDF("id", "c2", "c3sum").
  show

// +---+---+-----+
// | id| c2|c3sum|
// +---+---+-----+
// |  1|  1|  3.0|
// |  2|  2|  0.0|
// +---+---+-----+
```

Note that before transforming to a Dataset, `coalesce` is applied to c3 to replace `null` (if any) with an empty Array[Double].

Comment: The test case works but it doesn't work on my dataframe. There must be something unusual about my data.

Comment: @Thugnificent, not sure what error you're getting with your actual data.  I've updated my answer to handle `null`s in the array column, just in case that's the cause.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is using an `udf` (as you have tried). For it to work, you need to import and use `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf` to create an `udf`. Working example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val df = Seq(
    (1, 1, Seq(2.0, 1.0, 0.0)), 
    (2, 2, Seq(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), 
    (3, 3, Seq(0.0, 1.0, 0.0))
).toDF("id", "c2", "c3")

val mySum = udf((arr: Seq[Double]) => arr.sum)
val dfsum = df.withColumn("c3sum", mySum($"c3"))
```

Will give:

```
+---+---+---------------+-----+
| id| c2|             c3|c3Sum|
+---+---+---------------+-----+
|  1|  1|[2.0, 1.0, 0.0]|  3.0|
|  2|  2|[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]|  0.0|
|  3|  3|[0.0, 1.0, 0.0]|  1.0|
+---+---+---------------+-----+
```

Comment: Why would you change the default to val? Any performance improvement? I&#39;m anyways confused around choosing between the two. Say it&#39;s def it will be only computed once for each partition right and then serialised and sent to worker nodes? @shaido

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It's not working on my dataframe but I think the issue is on my end. Still trying to resolve.

Comment: @Thugnificent: This should work so maybe there is an issue with the data? What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: @Shaido Not getting any error. It just always returns only one or two values. I have thousands of arrays in this column, most are just [0,0,0,0...] But a few have nonzero values. Before transformation, df.distinct.show() shows many rows but after running aggregation I ALWAYS get df.distinct.count() == 2. The 2 values are "0.0" and the sum of all the other values.

Comment: @Thugnificent: Added a working example, you can try if it works for you or not. Using an udf like this should not have any impact at all on the number of rows, are you doing something more with the data?

Comment: Going to mark this closed. Got my code working by changing an earlier transformation and groupBy statement. Both solutions are workable.